# How to always append parameters for a Ggrep command?

Tags: search, plugin-fugitive, vimgrep

I'm using the Fugitive plugin. It has the `:Ggrep` command which is very useful for searching the repo.

One annoying thing is that I have huge `.map` files and I want to omit them from my search. I cannot modify the `.gitignore` and other files, I **can only modify what's related to vim**.

I'm using this:

```
:Ggrep foobar -- './*' ':(exclude)*.map'
```

How can I tell vim to always append `-- './*' ':(exclude)*.map'` and just write:

```
:Ggrep foobar
```

every time I'm searching for foobar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I don't think it's possible out of the box, you can work your way around this:

```
command! -nargs=1 GGrep Ggrep <q-args> -- './*' ':(exclude)*.map'
```

Then use the `GGrep` command instead of `Ggrep`:

```
:GGrep foobar
```

See:

- `:h command`
- `:h nargs`
- `:h <q-args>`

Comment: A creative solution, very nice, thanks :)